# Working macro returns error when run from form control

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to move all charts from `source` sheet to `destination` sheet. The following code works fine when I run it from the VB Editor. My `source` had two charts and both were successfully moved.

But when I try to run it using a `form button` from a `third sheet` (neither `source` nor `destination`), it only works for the first chart and then returns an error. Infuriatingly it retains a copy of the 'moved' chart in the `source` as well.

```
Sub moveAllCharts(source As String, destination As String)
    Dim chartObject As Object
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Application.Worksheets(source)).Name = destination
    For Each chartObject In Worksheets(source).ChartObjects
        chartObject.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, destination
    Next chartObject
End Sub
```

The code gets stuck inside the loop and returns a `The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type` error.

Comment: If you use debugger, and brake points you would know why it's happening. However you want us to check, excel would help a lot

Comment: No @Bharat you will not in this case :). Walser this is a very old problem which can be only sorted (I hope I am wrong) but activating the source sheet and selecting the chart). Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comments, this is a very old problem which can be only sorted (**I hope I am wrong**) by activating the source sheet and selecting the chart. If you do not do that, you will end up with `The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type Chart.` error

[image]

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub moveAllCharts(source As String, destination As String)
    Dim chartObject As Object
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Application.Worksheets(source)).Name = destination
    
    For Each chartObject In Worksheets(source).ChartObjects
        '~~> Need both of these
        Worksheets(source).Activate
        chartObject.Select
        
        ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, destination
    Next chartObject
End Sub
```

BTW, since you are forced to use `.Activate` and `.Select`, the above code should also include error handling. For example

```
Sub moveAllCharts(source As String, destination As String)
    Dim chartObject As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(source)
        
    On Error GoTo Whoa
        
    wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(source)).Name = destination
        
    For Each chartObject In ws.ChartObjects
        '~~> Need both of these
        ws.Activate
        chartObject.Select
            
        ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, destination
    Next chartObject
LetsContinue:
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]